# Creating user defined exception class-Getting null as answer(JAVA)

Tags: java, exception

I tried to implement the following question but I'm getting null as answer when trying to pass the value to the method. I can't seem to pass the value to the method transfer after calculating the new balance when withdrawing.

[image]

The Account class:

```
package Number3;

public class Account {

private int balance;
private int maxTransfer;

public Account()
{
    balance = 0;
    maxTransfer = 0;
}

public Account(int bal,int maxT)
{
    balance = bal;
    maxTransfer = maxT;
}

public void setBalance(int b)
{
    balance = b;
}

public int getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}

public void setMaxTransfer(int m)
{
    this.maxTransfer = m;
}

public int getMaxTransfer()
{
    return maxTransfer;
}

public void withdraw(int amount) throws insufficientFundException
{
    if(!(amount < balance))
    {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new insufficientFundException();
    }
}

public void transfer(int amount)
{
    balance = amount + balance;
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println("Current balance: "+getBalance());
}
}
```

The testAccount main:

```
package Number3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testAccount{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
    Account a = new Account();
    a.setBalance(1000);
    a.setMaxTransfer(10000);
    int choice,amount,acc;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    a.display();

    System.out.println("1. Withdraw \t\t 2. Transfer");
    System.out.println("Choose either 1 or 2");
    choice = input.nextInt();

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw: ");
        amount = input.nextInt();
        a.withdraw(amount); //where i assume the error is
        a.getBalance();
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        System.out.println("Enter amount to transfer: ");
        amount = input.nextInt();
        a.transfer(amount);
        a.getBalance();
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        System.out.print("Enter 1 or 2: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
    }
    }


}
catch(insufficientFundException ife)
{
    System.out.print(ife.getMessage());
}

}
}
```

And the class for the user defined exception:

```
package Number3;

public class insufficientFundException extends Exception{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("You don't have enough funds in your account.");

}

}
```

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an exception? Is the output wrong? Make sure to include all details of your issue.

Comment: When i have inputted the amount to withdraw, it is supposed to display the balance again but then i get null as answer. Even if i enter an amount exceeding the balance.

Comment: As an aside:  your exception is incorrect.  You should be passing the message to the constructor of Exception instead of creating another `main` method inside of it.  In the normal flow of your program, that `main` method will *never* be invoked.

Comment: Well, did you step through each line of code in your debugger?

Comment: @Makoto Can you show me how please? I'm new to that. Just been learning that in class.

Comment: Are you sure that the conditional in your `withdraw` method is correct?  And maybe your code should also be prepared for the fact that integers can be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Class should look like this

```
package Number3;

    public class InsufficientFundException extends Exception{

    public InsufficientFundException(String message){
      super(message);
    }
}
```

Then you create a new instance of this Exception class passing in the String value you want to have displayed during runtime

Par Example

```
public void withdraw(int amount) throws insufficientFundException
{
   if(!(amount < balance))
   {
       balance = balance - amount;
   }
   else
   {
       throw new InsufficientFundException("You do not have enough money in your account");
   }
}
```

Also I just came to realize that your if else statement might be wrong because your telling the program if the amount is not less than the balance, take amount out of the balance when you should be saying if the amount IS less than the balance take the money out of the account

like so

```
if(amount < balance)
   {
       balance = balance - amount;
   }
   else
   {
       throw new InsufficientFundException("You do not have enough money in your account");
   }
```

Comment: Why a `RuntimeException`?

Comment: For me the problem occurs during runtime, so i have RuntimeException, but it makes no difference if you also have Exception, both of them are pretty much the same thing

Comment: `RuntimeException` is for non-checked exceptions. They are very much *not* the same thing.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Also, it was printing null because i was not using the display method. I changed it to a.display() instead.

Comment: Glad I could help, just watch out for your if else loop :)

Answer (score 4):

You have implemented your custom Exception incorrectly. You need to call the super constructor in the Exception class with your message, like:

```
class MyCustomException extends Exception {

    MyCustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Like others have stated, you need to invoke your exception using the message like so:

```
throw new MyCustomException("Error message");
```

Answer (score 4):

This main method never going to be invoked. add your exception to your super class in constructor

```
package Number3;

public class insufficientFundException extends Exception{

    insufficientFundException(String msg){
       super(msg);
    }

}
```

in your code throw this exception when it occurs

```
if(balance-withdrawal<0){
   throw new insufficientFundException("Your error message");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First your are using a getter to get the balance\maxTransfer and not printing it.

You can't execute a transfer because after you withdraw the switch breaks and the execution ends.

Also pay attention you are implementing another main() method in your customized exception class.

Comment: Thanks i used a.display() instead and it printed the new balance.